# How to output products with attributes as table in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I found a solution how to output products with attributes as tables in category.tpl. But, I do need only one table with attributes names in heading, and products as rows of one single table. I wonder if someone can help me.

```
    <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
    <table class="attribute">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Picture</td>
          <td>Name</td>
          <?php if($product['attribute_groups']) { ?>
              <?php foreach($product['attribute_groups'] as $attribute_group) { ?>
                  <?php foreach($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) { ?>
                      <td><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?></td>
                  <?php } ?>
          <td>Price</td>
          <td>PDF</td>
          <td><!--Купить--></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><?php if ($product['thumb']) { ?>
            <div class="image"> <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="catalog/view/theme/gainta/image/pic.png " title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" /></a></div>
            <?php } ?></td>
          <td><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></td>
          <?php foreach($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) { ?>
          <td><?php echo $attribute['text']; ?></td>
          <?php } ?>
          <td><?php echo $product['price']; ?></td>
          <td><?php if (isset($product['file_href'])) { ?>
            <div class="pdf"> <a href="<?php echo $product['file_href']; ?>">PDF</a> </div>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <div class="pdf"></div>
            <?php } ?></td>
          <td><input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" class="button" /></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Do You realize that in Your code You have `foreach` in a `foreach` that is in another `foreach`? I am trying to avoid any situations with only one nested `foreach` (and thanks god there are really rare) but having two nested `foreach` loops is really an overkill... Anyway, what should be this HTML template good for? Is it Your attempt for solution or is it just Your working table of products in `category.tpl` (that is completely of no use to problem being asked)? And I thought that *table layouts* are out of fashion since 2000...

Comment: I`m not a programmer and this is the only solution I found so far. Yes, I do need tog get rid of this monstrous loop. In the end I need a single table with product in every row. That`s why I`m here for help.

PS: Table is used in here since it`s a tabular data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need to add `attrtibute_groups` to products array in `catalog/controller/product/category.php` (around line 240 ) 
find `'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],` and after that add the following line

```
'attribute_groups' => $this->model_catalog_product->getProductAttributes($result['product_id']),
```

then in your **category.tpl** file replace `<div class="product-list"> .. lots of code .. </div>`

with this

```
<table class="attribute">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Picture</td>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Attributes</td>
          <td>Price</td>
          <td>PDF</td>
          <td><!--Купить--></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><?php if ($product['thumb']) { ?>
            <div class="image"> <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="catalog/view/theme/gainta/image/pic.png " title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" /></a></div>
            <?php } ?></td>
          <td><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></td>
          <td>
            <?php foreach($product['attribute_groups'] as $attribute_group) { ?>
            <b><?php echo $attribute_group['name']; ?></b> <br>
            <?php foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) { ?>
              <b><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?></b> -->
              <?php echo $attribute['text']; ?><br>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
          </td>
          <td><?php echo $product['price']; ?></td>
          <td><?php if (isset($product['file_href'])) { ?>
            <div class="pdf"> <a href="<?php echo $product['file_href']; ?>">PDF</a> </div>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <div class="pdf"></div>
            <?php } ?></td>
          <td><input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" class="button" /></td>
        </tr>
      <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I removed your code of having attributes group as table header because it may become nasty if a products on category page have many different attributes group

---------------- **Edited with attrribute names as table header** -------------------

```
<?php $AllAttributes = array(); ?>
  <?php foreach ($products as $product) {
    foreach($product['attribute_groups'] as $attribute_group) {
    foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) {
      $attribute_name = $attribute['name'];
      if(!in_array($attribute_name, $AllAttributes)) {
        $AllAttributes[] = $attribute_name;
      }
    }
   }
   } ?>
  <table class="attribute">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Picture</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <?php for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($AllAttributes); $i++) { ?>
          <td><?php echo $AllAttributes[$i];?></td>
        <?php } ?>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>PDF</td>
        <td><!--Купить--></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><?php if ($product['thumb']) { ?>
          <div class="image"> <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="catalog/view/theme/gainta/image/pic.png " title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" /></a></div>
          <?php } ?></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></td>

        <?php for($i=0; $i <sizeof($AllAttributes) ; $i++) { ?>
          <td>
          <?php foreach($product['attribute_groups'] as $attribute_group) {
            foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) {
              if($attribute['name'] == $AllAttributes[$i]) { 
                echo $attribute['text'] . "</td>";
                continue 3;
               } 
            } ?>
          </td>
          <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
        <td><?php echo $product['price']; ?></td>
        <td><?php if (isset($product['file_href'])) { ?>
          <div class="pdf"> <a href="<?php echo $product['file_href']; ?>">PDF</a> </div>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <div class="pdf"></div>
          <?php } ?></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" class="button" /></td>
      </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

This code is liitle messy with nested for loops because of how `getProductAttributes` returns attribute . You can clean that up little bit by making a new function which return array of just attribute (which is currently a nested array with attribute groups)

Comment: Thanks, Chetan! But, I do need to have a table header with attributes taken from db, and <?php if($product['attribute_groups']) { ?> is a must. There will be different product groups and some of them will have some attributes (such as color and material) and some of them will not, depending on product group, "color" or "material" column have to be shown or have to be hidden. I need some solution to get attribute names only once and put them to header, then I need to get every other product as a table row.

Comment: @Mike note that attribute and attribute group are two different things. suppose you sell PC. then a attribute groups can be CPU and monitor. CPU can contain 5 attribute like clock speed, RAM etc and monitor may contain another 5 attributes, so there will be 10 attributes in 2 attribute groups. so you want 10 table headers or 2 table headers ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant attributes, not groups. I have two product groups: cases and accessories, cases have ~7 attributes ans accessories have 3 attributes, I want to have 7 headers for cases (plus price, pdf link etc.) and 3 for accessories.

Comment: `foreach` -> `foreach` -> `foreach` and a while after `foreach` -> `for` -> `foreach` -> `foreach` ... That's how I imagine lightweight solutions...

Comment: @shadyyx you might want to read note at the end of answer. `getProductAttributes()` returns attribute in a very nested form which requires two nested `foreach` loop and this whole thing is to repeated for each product so it should be inside another `foreach product loop`. Now add the user's requirement of attributes as header now you need another `for` loop to satisfy that requirement. the solution can be cleaned using `array_search()` etc but that's more or less same thing. i also suggested to make a new function which returns attribute in more simpler form and can reduce some `loops`

Comment: OK, I understand, but here on SO we **shouldn't** provide *quick'n'dirty* solutions. If You have no time to provide the correct solution then just push the OP the correct way (the steps to follow) and let him to write down the code for himself - it is eventhough the best way for OP to learn something. If You provide a dirty but working solution then OP uses it without thinking about it and then he will come back after a month that his product list is loading too long...